# 12 Angular Material Mat tabs in 2 rows how can I achieve it?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to use 12 mat tabs in 2 rows with angular material how can I achieve this with obviously one mat tab only selected?

The code provided is 12 separate tabs in 2 by collection of 6 each I am able to show it like that because the top selected tab is empty.

If inserted 12 in one container will give a slider which I don't want

[image: Click here for image]

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs animationDuration="100ms">
  <br>
  <mat-tab label="Events">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Venues">
    <app-clubs></app-clubs>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Festivals">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Concerts">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Restaurants">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Karaokes">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
</mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs animationDuration="100ms">
  <br>
  <mat-tab label="Events">
     <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Venues">
    <app-clubs></app-clubs>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Festivals">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Concerts">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Restaurants">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Karaokes">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
</mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs animationDuration="100ms">
  <br>
  <mat-tab label="Events">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Venues">
    <app-clubs></app-clubs>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Festivals">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Concerts">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Restaurants">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Karaokes">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
</mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs animationDuration="100ms">
  <br>
  <mat-tab label="Events">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Venues">
    <app-clubs></app-clubs>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Festivals">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Concerts">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Restaurants">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
  <mat-tab label="Karaokes">
    <app-events></app-events>
  </mat-tab> 
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Add you code to help you

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

use only one mat-tab-group and add this to your mat-tab-group

```
disablePagination="true"
```

https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup

then you could add the following css

```
.mat-tab-labels{ 
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: it works partly... Tabs who do not fit on the page anymore are hidden and unreachable, is there a way to get the second row of tabs below the first?

Comment: Hi Jibi, tnx for your answer. I tried without success. Then found this post, which worked for me.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68798369/show-angular-material-tabs-in-two-2-rows

Comment: In angular 16 the class selector is `.mat-mdc-tab-labels`