# Show Angular Material Tabs in two (2) rows

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am building a tabs component using `Angular Material Tabs` and as the number of tabs increase, it automatically starts scrolling horizontally. Instead of doing that, I want to break the tabs and show them in two (2) rows. How do I do this?

You can find the code here: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j7qdkz?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Please help me get this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `.mat-tab-labels` has `display:flex` if you want to show all tabs in two lines or more you can use `display: block`.

So you can solve this problem by `css` like this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-labels {
  /* display: flex; */ default display is flex change to block
  display: block !important;
}
```

[ForkedStackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qffbrn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

And the result:

[image]